# How to list all users along with user profile from ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: silverlight, membership

Right now I'm working with silverlight project and I'm stuck on how to list all of users and user profile together.

Now I'm using this method to get all user via WCF

```
public IEnumerable<MembershipServiceUser> GetAllUsers()
{
    return Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(u => new MembershipServiceUser(u));
}

public void FromMembershipUser(MembershipUser user)
{
    this.Comment = user.Comment;
    this.CreationDate = user.CreationDate;
    this.Email = user.Email;
    this.IsApproved = user.IsApproved;
    this.UserName = user.UserName;
}
```

I can get all user from those code above but I don't know how extactly to get user profile
eg. Firstname , Lastname , etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of `ProfileBase` and access the profile fields with the method `GetPropertyValue("propertyName")`, where `propertyName` is the name of your custom registration data.

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);
this.CustomProperty = profile.GetPropertyValue("customPropertyName");
```

I'm not 100% sure about the syntax, I come from a vb environment and haven't written any c# in a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProfileInfoCollection profiles = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
foreach (ProfileInfo pi in profiles)
{
        ProfileCommon p = Profile.GetProfile(pi.UserName);
        countries.Add(p.Country);        
}
```